# Converting Excel "JAN-20" in text format to 1/31/2020 in date format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-format

This question has two parts:

1. Converting the month and year into the date
2. Ensuring that new date is the end of each month, i.e. no individual date is provided in the original input, but the output has to assume that it is the end of each month.

I have tried a number of functions including `DATEVALUE()`, but I am stumped.

[image]

Comment: What does your starting data look like?

Comment: Will update my question with it.

Comment: Are those text strings or what? When you click on one of those cells, what is shown in the formula bar?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date to an unambiguous string, then use the `EOMONTH` function:

```
=EOMONTH(MID(A1,5,2) & "-" &LEFT(A1,3) & "-" & YEAR(TODAY()),0)
```

[image]

The above formula assumed, since you initially provided only the single text date `JAN-20` that the date represented `mmm-dd`.  If it is `mmm-yy` then you can use the same principal with a similar formula.  Just prepend the string with some number `1..28` representing a date within the month.

eg.

```
=EOMONTH("1 " & A1,0)
```

Comment: In this scenario what do A15 and A1 refer back to? I'm trying to follow the logic here: the EOMONTH function sets up the month, the LEFT function sets up the individual date, and the YEAR function sets up the year. Having said that, I assume A15 is the text "JAN-20" and A1 is an empty cell? That way it would just return the EOMONTH portion? Thank you for the help - this already looks much closer than anything I was able to arrive at.

Comment: Also - the TODAY function here will return 2020, I have a list of dates that include years besides 2020.

Comment: Your question does not mention that fact

Comment: @user1148508 The `A15` was a typo.  Should be `A1` and it is the location of your `Jan-20` in **Text** format.

Comment: @user1148508 Your example does not include the year, nor does your question mention anything of the sort.  It might be helpful if you let us know what date your text date represents.  Is it `mmm-dd` or `mmm-yy`?

Comment: @user1148508. See my edited answer for possible solution to the year issue.